# Eliminate duplicate lines from multiple files using awk or sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I wonder how can I eliminate duplicate lines from multiple files. I used this command to get the duplicate lines but it only shows me the lines in common:

```
sort *.txt | uniq -d | fgrep -f - *.txt | sort -t : -k 2
```

For example, if I have the following files:

file1.txt:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

file2.txt:

```
AAA
EEE
FFF
```

file3.txt:

```
BBB
ZZZ
...
```

file20.txt:

```
AAA
BBB
TTT
```

I want to have as results:

file1.txt:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

file2.txt:

```
EEE
FFF
```

file3.txt:

```
ZZZ
....
```

file20.txt:

```
TTT
```

Comment: Could you provide a succinct example of what you mean by “eliminate duplicate lines from multiple files”: are there duplicates inside each individual files, are the duplicated lines in different files, etc, and do you want to eliminate every occurrence of duplicated lines, or every occurence but one? In this case, if duplicates are across several files, in which file do you want to keep the line?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `-d` flag of `uniq`. That will show only the duplicated lines.

From `uniq --help`:

> ```
> -d, --repeated        only print duplicate lines, one for each group
> ```

Instead, use `uniq` with no arguments:

```
sort *.txt | uniq | ...
```

Or, more simply, `sort` can uniquify for you:

```
sort -u *.txt | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!Line[$0]++' *.txt
```

will print only once any string even if present in several files and/or in same file

with new OP constraint added (output in each *original* file)

```
awk '!Line[$0]++ > ( FILENAME ".new" )' *.txt
```

for redirection limitation in awk, output is redirected from `FileX.txt` to `FileX.txt.new`. Original file could be use with some change (not directly the purpose of the request)

Comment: also will preserve the order and no sorting is required.

Comment: right, not specified because OP use the sort (and easy to pipe at output). It use more memroy, keeping lines in memory via array index where multipipe could use temporary file if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Vim: open gvim (for instance) **with all your files as arguments**.
Then

1. Copy the following code into the clipboard

   ```
   let g:duplicate_finder={}
   function Remove_duplicates()
       " Get the buffer lines
       let buf_lines = getline(1, '$')
       " Reduce the buffer to one empty line
       execute '%d _'
       " Append to the buffer only lines never encountered before
       for cur_buf_line in buf_lines
           if !has_key(g:duplicate_finder, cur_buf_line)
               call append(line('$'), cur_buf_line)
               let g:duplicate_finder[cur_buf_line] = '1'
           endif
       endfor
       " Delete first line from the buffer
       execute '1d _'
   endfunction
   argdo call Remove_duplicates()
   ```

   and
2. In the gVim window, type `:@+`<kbd>return</kbd> to run the code.

An alternative is:

1. saving the code above to a file named `remove_duplicates.vim`, and
2. In the gVim window, type `:source /path/to/remove_duplicates.vim`<kbd>return</kbd>.

In order to save all buffers, then run `:xa`<kbd>return</kbd>